# Azure-mobile-apps-net-client disable Optimistic Concurrency

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I use Xamarin Forms with azure-mobile-apps-net-client with the .net backend. I already published the app but disabled the sync functions for now.

Now I'm implementing the missing sync functions. My problem is I made the following in my model classes before:

```
[Version]
public string Version { get; set; }
```

This enables Optimistic Concurrency. However I don't need it. Is there an simple way (on the server or client side) to disable Optimistic Concurrency?

Is it safe to remove the Version property from the client models? Or maybe there are better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimistic Concurrency is enabled/disabled on the client side.  If you remove the Version string, then optimistic concurrency is turned off.  However, this also removes Conflict Resolution.  The client record will always be accepted as the latest.